# Session on codeigniter not working perfectly

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have an issue regarding session (userdata/flashdata) on my code.

**Modal**

```
  public function loginCheck(){

    $email = $this->input->post('email');

    //encrypt password
    $this->load->library("hashing");
    $password = $this->hashing->incrypt($this->input->post('password'));    

    $this->params = array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password);


    $user = $this->findById();


    if(count($user)>0){
        $data = array(
            'email' => $user->email,
            'isLoggedIn' => 1,
            'user_id' => $user->id,
            'user_type' => $user->user_type
        );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

And my **Controller**

```
public function login(){

    $this->load->model('model_users');

    //if posted login 
    $submit = $this->input->post('submit');

    if($submit){

        $this->load->model('model_users');

        $rules = $this->model_users->rules;
        $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

        if($this->form_validation->run() == true){

            // user credential from model
            if($this->model_users->loginCheck()== true){
                redirect("admin/site/index");
            } else{
                 $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Oops! Invalid email and/ or password.');
                 redirect("admin/site/login");
            }
        }else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('message', 'Oops! Invalid email and/ or password.');
                redirect("admin/site/login");
        }

    }

     $this->loadPartialView("admin/login");
}
```

The session is not being set on **CI 3.0**. The function **set_userdata()** is not functioning well.

The manual session initializing is also having trouble.

Comment: The session library is loaded from autoload

Comment: Explain *in-depth* what exactly is happening and what debugging steps you have taken. This will help us narrow down the problem. "Not functioning well" and "having trouble" aren't really definitive comments that are addressable.

Comment: Thanks, 
I am using set_userdata function to set session for my system. But, its not saving sessions. Do i need to manage in any other place?

Comment: As long as you have autoloaded it - should be fine. Make sure that is the case. And for good measure maybe load it in your controller/model constructor to be safe (you can remove it later) just to see if that is perhaps the issue. You need to verify if  `if(count($user)>0){` is even reached inside. Inside add an echo or something to see. Try a bunch of debugging stuff like that.

Comment: When all else fails. Create a test controller, set a session variable and after echo. Reload the page, if it isn't there, you are having session issues. Check to make sure sess_save path is correct in config... (has to be set)

Answer (score 0):

Please try load Session Library into Controller and Modal before using it.

```
$this->load->library('session');
```

Comment: $this->load->library('session');

Not worked. Whats the difference in loading before and on autoload?

Comment: No difference really.

Answer (score 0):

i dont think if this is a good answer, but have you call your session in `view`? 
as i know ,

> CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared.

it can be found in [sesseion documentation](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html)

so in your view in `div` tag or other, its like

```
<?php echo $this->session->flashdata('message');?>
```

Answer (score 0):

First you can add library of session.

There are two way of add library.

1) You can add in controller method.

2) autoload in autoload.php file.